# Go parse template glob

Tags: go

Im currently doing the following

```
var (
    renderer = template.New("pigo")
)

func loadTemplate() {
    //log.Println(Config.String("template")+"/*.html")
    _, err := renderer.ParseGlob(Config.String("template")+"/*.html")
    log.Println(err)
}
```

This gives me no error. So then I make the following on a http request

```
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
renderer.ExecuteTemplate(w, "home.html", nil)
```

This executes the template BUT doesnt parse it what I mean is the response looks like this

```
[[ template "head_start.html" ]] 
[[ template "head_end.html" ]] 
<b>Hello</b>
[[ template "footer_start.html" ]] 
[[ template "footer_end.html" ]]
```

It doesnt seems to execute propertly. What I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

Set the delimiters to "[[" and "]]":

```
renderer = template.New("pigo").Delims("[[", "]]")
```

or change the template to use the default delimiters:

```
{{ template "head_start.html" }} 
{{ template "head_end.html" }} 
<b>Hello</b>
{{ template "footer_start.html" }} 
{{ template "footer_end.html" }}
```